# bindActorFactory...] not starting up the actor at Play Framework application startup

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, guice, actor

I have an Akka Actor named `MyActorin` in my Scala Play Framework application. I am binding this actor in a module named `MyModule`

```scala
class MyActor @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    log.info("[MyActor] Inside preStart")
    system.scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(initialDelay = 5.seconds, delay = 10.seconds, message = "1", receiver = self)(system.dispatcher)
  }
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "1" => log.info("[MyActor] Received Message")
  }
}
```

```scala
class MyModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bindActor[MyActor]("my-actor")
  }
}
```

And then in my application.conf I have
`play.modules.enabled += "com.learning.actors.MyModule"`

I have added logs in the actor's `preStart()` method but none of them are getting printed on application server startup.

I have manually `send(!_=)` the actor a message to initialize it but this is not the behavior I want. I want it to be up and running as soon as my play application starts.

How do I do that?

Comment: I guess you are following [scala akka play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaAkka) article. The details you provided are not enough to know what is the issue. Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks, @GastónSchabas Have added more details!

Comment: Are you injecting that actor anywhere? [scala guice lifecyle](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Component-lifecycle) says that **New instances are created every time a component is needed** and **Instances are created lazily when they are needed** unless you use [eagerly binding](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings). If the actor is not being injected anywhere, or the component where it is being injected is not called, the `preStart` will never happen

Comment: Correct but the bindActor handles the eagerBinding for me. Here is the definition of bindActor 

```def bindActor[T <: Actor: ClassTag](name: String, props: Props => Props = identity): Unit = {
    accessBinder
      .bind(classOf[ActorRef])
      .annotatedWith(Names.named(name))
      .toProvider(Providers.guicify(Akka.providerOf[T](name, props)))
      .asEagerSingleton()
  }
```

Specifically, observe the last part `.asEagerSIngleton()`

Comment: It Is hard to read code in the comments due to formatting applied. Please edit your post and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also add your `build.sbt` and which version of play you are using. Without doing that I will continue guessing what is happening in your project instead of suggest a proper solution